# Stop SQL Server Management Studio from adding comment to stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

How do I prevent SQL Management Studio (10.50.2500.0) from adding this to the beginning of every stored procedure when I right-click/Modify them?

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[myproc]    Script Date: 11/05/2011 16:20:05 ******/
```

Comment: Which Management Studio are you using?

Comment: 10.50.2500.0. I edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Hm...  This should be an option.

Comment: I asked you because i use several on diffrent machines and not all of it has that option. The one that has it is 10.50.1617.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scripting options stay here : Tools > Options > SQL Server Object Explorer > Scripting.

Set "Include descriptive headers" to false.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, that got rid of the comment. Anyone have ideas on the ANSI_NULLS or QUOTED_IDENTIFIER? I toggled the settings at the DB level and there was no change.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff Why do you want to omit the ANSI_NULLS and QUOTED_IDENTIFER settings from your procedure scripts? It's usually a good idea to be explicit. Each procedure takes this setting independently, and correct behavior may depend on the setting. Scripting it out protects you from bugs when you use the script to create the procedure in a database that has a different default setting.